# Convert xarray dimensions to latitude and longitude

Tags: python, geospatial, python-xarray

I am looking at satellite netcdf format data using xarray, but I first need to convert the dimensions from scanline (the y index corresponding with the satellite scan direction) and ground-pixel (the x index corresponding with the direction adjacent to the scan direction) to latitude and longitude. The latitude and longitude dimensions are currently defined as coordinates in the format: latitude(scanline, ground_pixel). How can I convert these into dimensions of latitude(latitude) and longitude(longitude)? I'd like to be able to plot and query the xarray using lat lon coordinates and xarray query/plotting functions.

Here's a picture of the xarray. I've not yet been able to reproduce a simple example of this data format, with the two dimensions defined for the latitude and longitude coordinates.

[image]

The latitude and longitudes in geographical coordinates can be found using: ds.latitude.values and ds.longitude.values, but these are subset into the scanline and ground-pixel arrays. I think I need to collapse these into a single list of latitudes/longitudes.

Comment: I don't think so... your data is also structured as a 2D array indexed by scanline and ground pixel. your data is just not on a regular grid. that's fine, but you're going to have to figure out how to work with your data in it's current form, or else transform your data somehow, which will likely involve manipulating the data (e.g. by regridding and averaging observations within a grid cell). what is it you're trying to do?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have other xarray data variables in the regular lat lon grid format (e.g., soil moisture data), and I'd like to compare them directly with the atmospheric data that is in the grid format described here. To do so, it would be easiest if they have the same dimensions. I'm currently looking at using xarrays groupby_bins function. I'll post the solution back here if I can find one.

Comment: As @MichaelDelgado says, you will need to restructure the data. It sounds like you want to match up gridded Netcdf data with this ungridded (essentially point observations) satellite data. Consider using something like xesmf to regrid the gridded data to the lat/Lon pairings in the satellite data.

Comment: Thanks, I think most possibly you're right, but I'm still a bit confused as the data is gridded in lat and lon on an ~7km grid, but it's just a strange 2 dimensional format that I'm not familiar with. The lat and long coordinates are gridded, but have their values defined in the 2 dimensions, scanline and ground_pixel. I can access what I assumed was their gridded values using ds.latitude.values.flatten()

Comment: I've looked a bit more into it, and the data is gridded, but it's not a regular grid, and the pixel spacing ranges between ~7 and 20km. No two pixels seem to have the exact same spacing. I'll have another think about how to regrid it and I'll look at using xesmf. Thanks both.

Comment: I think as Michael suggested, it may be best for me just to work with the data in its current form, e.g., I can use xarrays select function to extract the nearest value within a defined maximum distance corresponding with locations in the other datasets that I'm interested in comparing the data with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data was on an irregular grid and I used the following method to regrid it (see the XESMF docs for further info: https://xesmf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebooks/Pure_numpy.html):

```
%%time
import xesmf as xe

lats = ds_subset.latitude.values
lons = ds_subset.longitude.values

# creating the lat and lon regular grid arrays
# I've just used 100 to test the method quickly, a larger value is required to best represent the resolution of the original data

grid_lats = np.linspace(lats.min(), lats.max(), 100)
grid_lons = np.linspace(lons.min(), lons.max(), 100)

# make the grid that the data will be regridded to
new_grid = xr.Dataset({'lat':(['lat'],grid_lats), 'lon':(['lon'],grid_lons)})

# use periodic=False if either or both the lat and lon dimensions are not regular. I found that the nearest neighbour method works the best. There's data loss with bilinear.
regridder = xe.Regridder(ds_subset,new_grid, 'nearest_s2d', periodic=False,)

# regrid the data
ds_new = regridder(ds_subset)

ds_new
```

Answer (score 1):

Given your description of the data, it seems like the data is observational data for a set of satellites (or sensor passes/scanlines) which are reported for all pixels where each satellite is in range for a given pass. Maybe each of the 188 scanlines had as many as 109 pixels within range on that day. They're essentially little circles or blobs within the larger grid, with each blob indexed by the scanline ID.

Since this is such a small dataset, the easiest way to convert this to a grid would probably be to drop into pandas to group on pixels and then convert back to xarray. The following will return the mean value observed for each latitude/longitude observation:

```py
gridwise_mean = (
    ds_subset.to_dataframe()
    .dropna(how="all")
    .groupby(["latitude", "longitude"])
    .methane_mixing_ratio_bias_corrected
    .mean()
    .to_xarray()
)
```

Note that this will return a nLons x nLats array. If you have good coverage of all pixels, and the latitude/longitudes are truly on a regular grid, then this will likely be a pretty reasonable result to work with, and plotting a colormesh with e.g. `gridwise_mean.plot()` should return a nice plot of the average observation for each pixel.

> ***Warning:*** If your latitudes/longitudes are not on a regular grid, this could explode your memory. At worst, if each data point has a unique lat/lon value attached, the result would be (188 * 109) ^ 2 = 420 million points, or about 3.1 GB, with only one non-NaN data point per lat/lon pair. This gets larger fast if you use this method on a larger number of points.
>
> To diagnose whether you have such an issue, you could first compute the number of unique latitudes and longitudes in the dataset with e.g. `np.unique(ds_subset.latitude)` and make sure the product of the number of unique lats and lons is a reasonably small number, and is much smaller than the total number of points in the original dataset.

Other summary stats such as the count, std. dev., min, and max might also be useful to know, so you could compute multiple summary statistics with:

```py
gridwise_summary = (
    ds_subset.to_dataframe()
    .groupby(["latitude", "longitude"])
    .methane_mixing_ratio_bias_corrected
    .agg(["mean", "count", "std", "max", "min"])
    .to_xarray()
)
```

This will return an `xr.Dataset` where the variables are the above reductions, and can be accessed with e.g. `gridwise_summary["max"]`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time to give this answer. It turns out the data is on an irregular grid. I've upvoted your answer though as I think it could be very useful for someone else who does have a regular grid defined this way. I've been able to use xesmf to regrid to a regular data. I'll add this method below.

Comment: Awesome! Glad to hear you figured this out, and thanks for taking the time to follow up and answer yourself! This is a fairly common wrinkle people encounter when working with this type of observational data so I think your answer could be a great resource too!